# Trying to create a backup of a .txt file that would rename the suffix of the txt file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to create a backup of a txt file too e.g thisfileisabackup.txt.bak_(current date I have yet to figure out how to print) How do i print current date and time into the new suffix of the txt file?

I've tried to change the suffix between cp $myfile $place -S .bak_;date and cp $myfile $place -S .bak_$newextension where i have put newextension=;date. The date gets printed out in the terminal rather than being saved as the new suffix along with .bak

## Current shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "File to backup"
read myfile

#checks if $myfile exists
if [ -f "$myfile" ] ; then
echo "Where do you want the backup stored"
read place
newextension=;date

#stores the backup to x place (place is defined by read place)
cp $myfile $place -S .bak_$newextension

else echo "$myfile does not exist"
```

I expect the output of something like thisisabackup.txt.bak_tor 25 apr 2019 17:55:12 CEST

The current output is only thisisabackup.txt.bak_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), and don't forget to quote your variables.

```
newextension="$(date)"
cp -- "$myfile" "$place" -S ".bak_$newextension"
```

or just:

```
cp -- "$myfile" "$place" -S ".bak_$(date)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using command substitution correctly. The right format would be something like this:

```
newextension=$(date)
```